# Azure AD B2C Login with social accounts

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Question on Azure AD B2C
If I enabled the social media authentication for Azure AD B2C  and then a user logged on with his Facebook account  then later joe signs in with the same email  but using his twitter account, my question here is will Azure AD consolidate those accounts or will I end up with the same email added twice in the Azure AD B2C Directory ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior will create two separate accounts.

You can link the accounts when detected, samples [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples#account-linking).